# Force MATCH to return a certain number of results

Tags: mysql

I am using MATCH in a query but sometimes the query returns no results. What can I do to force MATCH to return results, even if the results are not a match? I want the query to return four results. If the results are not a match then they should be random.

e.g. I want to get the two matches for the word 'Foo' plus two more random rows, making four results in total:

```
ID  TITLE
1   Carl
2   I am a title
3   Foo
4   Bar
5   Foobar
6   Title
```

The query should return something like:

```
ID  TITLE
3   Foo
5   Foobar
2   I am a title
6   Title
```

I tried:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Entries
WHERE
    MATCH(Title) AGAINST("Foo")
UNION
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Entries
    ORDER BY 
        RAND()
    )
LIMIT 4
```

I feel like this query should work, and it does, except the results that are not a match are not random for some reason, they are the same results every time.

Comment: could you elaborate, you want all that match and don't match, this desn't make sense, also it would help if youadd some data, to show which rows you want retireved and which not

Comment: added some data

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Indexes don-'t work that way.

They find whole Words and combinations of those
Use instead the normal comparison [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) to find your rows

The ORDER BY and the LIMIT have to be in the (),because mysql interprets them as belonging to the complete query (SELECT UNION SELCT)

> ```
> SELECT
>     *
> FROM
>     Entries
> WHERE
>     `Title` LIKE ('foo%')
> UNION
> (SELECT
>     *
> FROM
>     Entries
> WHERE
>     ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
>                FROM
>                  Entries
>                WHERE
>                 `Title` LIKE ('foo%'))
> ORDER By Rand()
> LIMIT 4)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | TITLE       
> -: | :-----------
>  3 | Foo         
>  5 | Foobar      
>  2 | I am a title
>  4 | Bar         
>  1 | Carl        
>  6 | Title
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     *
> FROM
>     Entries
> WHERE
>     `Title` LIKE ('foo%')
> UNION
> (SELECT
>     *
> FROM
>     Entries
> WHERE
>     ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
>                FROM
>                  Entries
>                WHERE
>                 `Title` LIKE ('foo%'))
> ORDER By Rand()
> LIMIT 2)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | TITLE 
> -: | :-----
>  3 | Foo   
>  5 | Foobar
>  4 | Bar   
>  1 | Carl
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c180fac2dec08f949c0d3be1072572f)*